# Counting unique occurences of country in a php array and adding them to a statistics array

Tags: php, loops, math, multidimensional-array, counting

**PARSED DATA**

I have a list of visitors visiting a web page, every time someone visits an entry is put into the database which logs amongst other things their Country. This information is then pulled from the database in the following format;

```
array(2641071)
{ 

  [0]=> object(Visitor)#1 (11)                   
  { 

       ["visitor_id"]=> string(1) "1" 
       ["visitor_time"]=> string(19) "2020-05-28 01:22:34" 
       ["visitor_ip"]=> NULL 
       ["visitor_hostname"]=> NULL 
       ["visitor_port"]=> string(5) "19660" 
       ["visitor_country"]=> string(5) "Italy" 
       ["visitor_alpha_3"]=> string(3) "ITA" 
       ["visitor_city"]=> string(4) "Roma" 
       ["visitor_continent"]=> string(6) "Europe" 
       ["visitor_timezone"]=> string(3) "GMT" 
       ["visitor_user_agent"]=> NULL 
   } 

   [1]=> object(Visitor)#2 (11)                   
   { 

       ["visitor_id"]=> string(1) "1" 
       ["visitor_time"]=> string(19) "2020-05-28 01:22:34" 
       ["visitor_ip"]=> NULL 
       ["visitor_hostname"]=> NULL 
       ["visitor_port"]=> string(5) "19660" 
       ["visitor_country"]=> string(5) "United Kingdom" 
       ["visitor_alpha_3"]=> string(3) "GBR" 
       ["visitor_city"]=> string(4) "London" 
       ["visitor_continent"]=> string(6) "Europe" 
       ["visitor_timezone"]=> string(3) "GMT" 
       ["visitor_user_agent"]=> NULL 
   } 

   [2]=> object(Visitor)#3 (11)                   
   { 

       ["visitor_id"]=> string(1) "1" 
       ["visitor_time"]=> string(19) "2020-05-28 01:22:34" 
       ["visitor_ip"]=> NULL 
       ["visitor_hostname"]=> NULL 
       ["visitor_port"]=> string(5) "19660" 
       ["visitor_country"]=> string(5) "France" 
       ["visitor_alpha_3"]=> string(3) "FRA" 
       ["visitor_city"]=> string(4) "Paris" 
       ["visitor_continent"]=> string(6) "Europe" 
       ["visitor_timezone"]=> string(3) "GMT" 
       ["visitor_user_agent"]=> NULL 
    } 

   [3]=> object(Visitor)#4 (11)                   
   { 

       ["visitor_id"]=> string(1) "1" 
       ["visitor_time"]=> string(19) "2020-05-28 01:22:34" 
       ["visitor_ip"]=> NULL 
       ["visitor_hostname"]=> NULL 
       ["visitor_port"]=> string(5) "19660" 
       ["visitor_country"]=> string(5) "France" 
       ["visitor_alpha_3"]=> string(3) "FRA" 
       ["visitor_city"]=> string(4) "Paris" 
       ["visitor_continent"]=> string(6) "Europe" 
       ["visitor_timezone"]=> string(3) "GMT" 
       ["visitor_user_agent"]=> NULL 
    } 

}
```

**DATA TRAVERSAL**

This information is stored in a variable called $visitors as can be seen below;

```
<?php

$visitors = $sql->get_visitors();

if ($visitors != NULL)// If items exist
{

    $Visitors_Countries = array();

    foreach($visitors as $visitor)
    {
        array_push($Visitors_Countries, $visitor->visitor_country);
    }

    $Visitors_Countries_Keys = array();
    $i = 0;
    foreach($Visitors_Countries as $Countries)
    {
        if(!in_array($Visitors_Countries[$i], $Visitors_Countries_Keys))
        {
            array_push($Visitors_Countries_Keys, $Visitors_Countries[$i]);
        }
        $i++;
    }

    $Country_Stats = array();
    $index = 0;
    echo '<ul>';

    foreach($Visitors_Countries_Keys as $Country_Key)
    {
        foreach($Visitors_Countries as $Country)
        {
             if($Countries_Key === $Country)
             {
                 $Country_Stats[$Country_Key][0] = $Country_Stats[$Country_Key][0]+1;
                 echo '<li><b>Key:</b> '.$Country_Key.' <b>Country:</b> '.$Country.' <b>Count:</b> '.$Country_Stats[$Country_Key][0].'</li>';
             }
         }
    }
    echo '</ul>';

?>
```

**PROBLEM - COUNT UNIQUE OCCURRENCES**

The problem I am having is counting how many of the unique values there is and storing this information in a statistics array to be then displayed in a table in the future.

Can someone look at the code I have supplied and point me in the right direction so I can solve this problem. Lack of sleep is clouding my mind...

**PROBLEM LOCATION**

The part of the code I am having trouble with follows;

```
foreach($Visitors_Countries_Keys as $Country_Key)
{
    foreach($Visitors_Countries as $Country)
    {
        if($Countries_Key === $Country)
        {
            $Country_Stats[$Country_Key][0] = $Country_Stats[$Country_Key][0]+1;
            echo '<li><b>Key:</b> '.$Country_Key.' <b>Country:</b> '.$Country.' <b>Count:</b> '.$Country_Stats[$Country_Key][0].'</li>';
        }
    }
}
```

**THE GOAL**

The goal is to have a statistics array of unique countries and how many times a visit came from each country.

```
$Country_Stats = {

["Italy"]=> int(3) 500,
["United Kingdom"]=> int(4) 1000,
["France"]=> int(3) 300,

}
```

**SOLUTION**

Thanks to Nigel Ren, who was very close, the answer was;

```
if($Countries_Key === $Country)
{
    $Country_Stats = array_count_values ( $Visitors_Countries );
}
```

This now gives me this;

```
array(16) 
{ 
    ["Italy"]=> int(1) 
    ["United Kingdom"]=> int(1) 
    ["France"]=> int(2) 
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at [`array_count_values()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)?

Comment: Yes, I tried that first, but I am still trying to get my head around the best way to go about it.

Comment: It is this part that I'm trying to get my head around $Country_Stats[$Country_Key][0] = $Country_Stats[$Country_Key][0]+1; The storing of the information in a $country_Stats array.

Comment: Might be something like `$Country_Stats = array_count_values ( $Visitors_Countries_Keys );`

Comment: I'll have a go at that...

Comment: You were close, it was $Country_Stats = array_count_values ( $Visitors_Countries);

Comment: Put that as an answer and I'll put it as accepted.

Comment: It's easier in PHP 7 `$result = array_count_values(array_column($visitors, 'visitor_country'));`